# Hibernate Sequence Conflict after using Audited annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using hibernate in my spring boot application
my domain model is like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "skill")
@Audited
public class Skill implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;
}
```

The increment size of sequence is 50 and is working properly
but when I add Envers Audited annotation I see this error

> conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [50] and [1]

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: Are you sure that it's because of hibernate envers? From the looks of it, it appears that you have sequenceGenerator defined in multiple places, once with increment size 1 and one with the default. Can you please check to make sure that you are not redefining the sequence in other entities?

Comment: yes, because when I remove @Audited annotation I don't see the error anymore

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code to get this behavior? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I'm using oracle PDB
have you tried with oracle?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate / Envers are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like an Envers problem but a general mapping problem.

When you add an `@Audited` annotation, that simply informs Envers that it should inspect that particular entity mapping during Hibernate bootstrap and create the necessary audit objects to store the entity state during each transaction.

The generated Envers objects use their own sequence generators and primary key.   The user defined generation strategy, sequences, etc are all ignored in the Envers object because the associated column is meant to just be a copy/pass-thru value, nothing special.

In other words, the Envers table would have a PK defined that mirrors this POJO:

```
@Embeddable
public class EnversSkillId implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "REV", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer rev;
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;
}
```

When Envers generates the audit record, it automatically uses its internal sequence generator to get the next value and assign it to `EnversSkillId#rev` and copies your entity's `id` value directly into the `EnversSkillId#id` property.

So as mentioned in the comments, your problem is very unlikely related to Envers.